# Understanding steady state in heat transfer on a molecular level

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I am trying to get to a molecular understanding of what happens before a steady state is achieved. I understand that macroscopically, the temperature of any point along the rod won't change when steady state is achieved, and dQ/dt will be constant everywhere. Mathematically, it makes sense that in steady state the atoms cannot store additional heat as this would lead to a rise in the measured temperature . However, how exactly is this steady state achieved?

Comment: The classic explanation is that  on average, a group of hotter particles collides more frequently with a group of colder particles that the latter collides with the former, thereby transfer energy from the former to the latter and evening out the temperature. Is this the type of answer you're looking for?

Comment: @Chemomechanics not exactly, I want to understand how heat current is somewhat analogous to the electric current.

Comment: @nova Just Google "electric current heat analogy".

Comment: @BobD , I understand the analogy mathematically, I found no explanations of  what is happening on the molecular level

Comment: @nova the analogy doesn't extend to the molecular level.

Comment: @BobD how do they differ?